# Regex to remove the end of a URL

Tags: regex

Ok first off I am using built-in .NET regex this I what I was told I am using. I am using the group function `A(.*?)B` than I am replacing it with nothing (basically removing it). What I am doing is removing some unwanted stuff from the end of a url I am scraping.

But the problem is for "B" I am using the quote which needs to be in there. Is there a way to say remove everything between A and b But not A and B? But A and B has to be used as markers in this example. I hope I explained this well enough.

Just in case I didn't I'll use an example random words and spaces nothing to use as indicators on either site "example.com" sometimes space no space sometimes words letters, etc. Now I want example.com with the quotes but everything changes on each side including spaces.

But I need example.com including the quotes so I cant just use `"(.*?)"` because once I use the replace function it wont get the quotes which I need to keep.

Ok rewording this `A(.*?)B` replace essentially I am reving whats in between A and B with nothing which is fine But i want to keep A and B i cannot use any characters or words before or after A and B because they are random and change for example how would you remove this: "example.com" but keep the quotes when everything before the quotes and inside the quotes is changing.

Comment: I fixed the asterisks for you (you need to surround the regexen with backticks, so the `*`s don't get interpreted as markdowns).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you reword it to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookaround assertion:

I don't know the exact syntax for the regex flavour you're using but you can adapt this to your language.

```
replace (?<=A).*?(?=B) by nothing
```